# "Remember a time when..." or "remember the time when..."?

Tags: articles, definite-article, indefinite-article

Could you tell which article I use in the following sentence: *a* or *the*?

> Do you remember **a**/**the** time when we went fishing and we forgot bait.

If both article possible, could you tell me what would be the difference in meaning then?

Comment: Consider what the indefinite and definite articles do - **a** time is some unspecified time out of possibly more than one time; **the** time is on particular time only.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would use "a" if I was asking whether the other person remembered ever going fishing with me and forgetting the bait. I would use "the" if I had a particular occasion in mind, and I would be implying that I thought there was only one occasion.